# App is getting crashed in while creating Uri uri

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.renu.customlead;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by RENU on 2/4/2018.
 */

public class MainLandingPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String filename = "MySampleFile.txt";
    private String filepath = "MyFileStorage";
    File myInternalFile;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }

    public void AddLead(View view) {
        DatabaseHelper dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Leads ", null);
        int n=curCSV.getCount();
        if (n >= 1) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity3.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(MainLandingPage.this, "No Field has been declared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    public void SendCsv(View view) {
        sendEmail();
    }

    public void DeleteRecord(View view) {
        DatabaseHelper dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Leads where id <> 1", null);
        int n = curCSV.getCount();
        if (n > 1) {
            deleteRecordALL();
            Toast.makeText(MainLandingPage.this, "Leads Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainLandingPage.this, "No Leads to be Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void DeleteAll(View view) {
        DatabaseHelper dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Leads ", null);
        int n=curCSV.getCount();
        if (n > 1) {
            deleteRecordALL();
            Toast.makeText(MainLandingPage.this, "Leads Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(MainLandingPage.this, "No Leads to be Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    protected void deleteRecordALL() {
        DatabaseHelper dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        //SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
        //db1.execSQL("delete from Leads");
        Log.d("Delete: ", "Deleting ..");
        dbhelper.deleteRec();

    }
    public void createField(View view){
        Intent intenti = new Intent(MainLandingPage.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intenti);
    }

    // export sqlite content to csv
//    private void exportDB() {
//
//
//    }
    protected void sendEmail() {

        //File dbFile = getDatabasePath("LeadsManager.db");   /storage/emulated/0
        DatabaseHelper dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

        ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File directory = contextWrapper.getDir(filepath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        myInternalFile = new File(directory , filename);
        //File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "data.csv");

        /*File mfolder = new File(getFilesDir().getPath());
        File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.renu.customlead/files" + "/data.csv");

        if (!mfolder.exists()) {
            mfolder.mkdirs();
        }
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Log.e("Main file name", file.getName());
        Log.e("Internalpath",getCacheDir().getPath());
        Log.e("Path",getFilesDir().getPath());
        Log.e("fileexists", String.valueOf(file.exists()));
        Log.e("Path",Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
*/
        try {
            //file.createNewFile();
            //CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));


            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myInternalFile);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Leads ", null);
            //myOutWriter.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());
            while (curCSV.moveToNext()) {
                //Which column you want to exprort
                String arrStr[] = {curCSV.getString(0), curCSV.getString(1)};
                Log.e("firstsql",arrStr[1]);
                Log.e("firstsql1",arrStr[0]);
                //myOutWriter.append(arrStr[0]);
                myOutWriter.append(arrStr[1]);
                myOutWriter.append("\n");
            }
            myOutWriter.close();
            curCSV.close();
            Log.e("Main", String.valueOf(myInternalFile.length()));

        } catch (Exception sqlEx) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
        }
        Log.i("Send email", "");
        String[] TO = {""};
        String[] CC = {""};
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
//        emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Lead created as of " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, myInternalFile.getAbsolutePath());
//        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(myInternalFile));
        Log.e("ppppp", myInternalFile.getName());
        emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
//        emailIntent.setType("text/*");
      Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainLandingPage.this, "com.example.renu.customlead",myInternalFile);
        //data/user/0/com.example.renu.customlead/app_MyFileStorage/MySampleFile.txt
        //com.example.renu.customlead/files/MySampleFile.txt
        //Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.example.renu.customlead/files/MySampleFile.txt");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

        Log.e("xxyyxx", myInternalFile.getName());
        Log.e("xxyyxxx", myInternalFile.getPath());
        Log.e("xxyyxxxx", myInternalFile.getAbsoluteFile().getName());
        String myData="";
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myInternalFile);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
            BufferedReader br =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                myData = myData + "\n" + strLine;
            }
            Log.e("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",myData);
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, myData);
        try {
            //startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,"Sending mail Done "),1);
            finish();
            Log.i("Finished sending email", "email xxxx");
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(MainLandingPage.this, "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

the program is getting failed with below error

```
03-07 11:50:24.524 27630-27630/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
           Process: com.example.renu.customlead, PID: 27630
           java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261)
               at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11159)
               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23748)
               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
            Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261) 
               at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11159) 
               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23748) 
               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386) 
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.example.renu.customlead/app_MyFileStorage/MySampleFile.txt
               at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:711)
               at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:400)
               at com.example.renu.customlead.MainLandingPage.sendEmail(MainLandingPage.java:182)
               at com.example.renu.customlead.MainLandingPage.SendCsv(MainLandingPage.java:61)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261) 
               at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11159) 
               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23748) 
               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Comment: *Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.example.renu.customlead/app_MyFileStorage/MySampleFile.txt*

Comment: Thank you but after changing the path also it is getting crashed  <files-path name="external_files" path="." />